# Update Apache to version 2.4.50 on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache

I am having some issues installing Apache 2.4.50 on amazon Linux, originally, I had an Amazon Linux AMI and tried to do Sudo yum update httpd -y

I wanted this to update the Apache version to the latest, but it only went as far as 2.4.48 and said it was the latest version,
while looking into this I saw that the Amazon AMI was now deprecated and was in maintenance mode only.

I decided to spin up a new server using Amazon Apache2 thinking this would solve my issues, but once I installed the LAMP and ran HTTPD -v
it still showed ‘Package httpd-2.4.48-2.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version’

I am aware that there is a critical issue with 2.4.48 CVE-2021-40438 and issue Apache 2.4.49 has a new zero-day critical vulnerability associated with it that can lead to a path traversal attack, so I need to get to 2.4.50.

Any help on how I can update to this version would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/489008/how-do-i-update-apache-to-2-2-24-on-aws-instance

Comment: Thank you for this, could you point me in the direction of installing from source anyway, although the link you pointed to suggests against it, it may be something I have to do.

Comment: I would start with the [Download Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) page.

Comment: Will give it a go thanks.